# Import Workflow using MetadataService or CrmService

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I've been able to import entities from an XML file into my Dynamics instance using ImportXmlRequest as follows:

> // Create the import request
>
> ImportXmlRequest importRequest = new
> ImportXmlRequest {
> ParameterXml =@"<entities><entity>MyFirstEntity<entity>MySecondEntity</entities><nodes/><securityroles/><settings/><workflows/></importexportxml>"
> };
>
> string customizationPath =
> "entityCustomizations.xml";
>
> // Pass the stream of customization XML to the import request using
>
> (StreamReader sr = new
> StreamReader(customizationPath))
> {
> string customizationXml =
> sr.ReadToEnd();
> importRequest.CustomizationXml =
> customizationXml;
> }
>
> // Import the customizations
> myCrmService.Execute(importRequest);

That works fine.

I also need to import workflows from an XML file into my Dynamics instance. I tried using the same approach but I kept getting the following error: '0x80040216 unrecognized format'.

I was able to get it working by adding the XML file containg the workflows to a ZIP file and then importing the ZIP file using ImportCompressedAllXmlRequest.

Is ImportCompressedAllXmlRequest the only way to import workflows or am I missing something obvious with the ImportXmlRequest?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually had a stupid bug in my code. I was able to use ImportXmlRequest to import workflows by setting the ImportXmlRequest's ParameterXml as follows:

```
<importexportxml>
    <entities/>
    <nodes/>
    <securityroles/>
    <settings/>
    <workflows>
        <workflow>{97db1a25-af1c-4534-9805-c867d6585c8a}</workflow>
    </workflows>
</importexportxml>"
```